# Redux-form get the value from other tab/component

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have to implement a form with a bit less than 30 different fields.
So I decided to split them in 2 differents container component with two tabs to navigate between them.

I use redux-form to handle the data binding.

For on component I can get the value from `handleSubimit` of one component. But the final validation must be in the last tab only. From here I only have access to the value of the second tab. Like the data from the store where wipe out.

How can I access the store where my previous data should be ?

**TabNavigationBar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import TabNavigationItem from './TabNavigationItem';

const TabNavigationBar = ({ onTabChange, activeTab }) => {
  const tabList = [
    { hasIcon: 'fas fa-user-circle', hastext: 'Information Utilisateur' },
    { hasIcon: 'fas fa-file-alt', hastext: 'Informations contrat' }
  ];

  const clickOnTab = tabNumer => {
    onTabChange(tabNumer);
  };

  return (
    <div className="columns">
      <div className="column is-offset-one-quarter-desktop is-offset-one-thirds-tablet is-half-desktop is-one-thirds-tablet">
        <div className="tabs is-toggle is-fullwidth">
          <ul>
            {tabList.map((tab, i) => (
              <TabNavigationItem
                key={i}
                tabSelected={() => clickOnTab(i)}
                hasClass={activeTab === i ? 'is-active' : ''}
                hasIcon={tab.hasIcon}
                hasText={tab.hastext}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TabNavigationBar;
```

**UserForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import CiviliteRadioButton from './CiviliteRadioButton';
import NameInputs from './NameInputs';
import AddressInputs from './AddressInputs';
import MailAndDOB from './MailAndDOB';
import TelephoneInputs from './TelephoneInputs';

let UserForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CiviliteRadioButton />
      <NameInputs />
      <AddressInputs />
      <MailAndDOB />
      <TelephoneInputs />
    </div>
  );
};

UserForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'form1',
  initialValues: {
    user: {
      adresse: {
        country: 'France'
      },
      civilite: 'Madame'
    }
  }
})(UserForm);

export default UserForm;
```

**ContractForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import InputItem from '../InputItem';

import ContratInputsList from './contratInputList';

let ContratForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  const submit = values => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="columns is-multiline ">
        {ContratInputsList.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="column is-half" key={i}>
              <InputItem spec={item.spec} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="columns">
        <div className="column">
          <div className="field is-grouped is-grouped-right">
            <input
              className="button is-primary"
              onClick={handleSubmit(submit)}
              type="submit"
              value="Envoyer"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ContratForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'form2'
})(ContratForm);

export default ContratForm;
```

**EDIT**

When I click on my tabs, redux-form/DESTROY is called and erase form1's data.

[image]

Comment: I see why you only get values from one form, but it's hard to give an answer solving your problem. On submit of every tab you must sent the values to a top level state/store and then retrieve them later to get the full picture. Right now every form is on it's own. So in general make sure your `handleSubmit` for the forms sents the data to the upper level component - eg. the TabNavigationBar - store it there and then hand it down to the respective tabs again, so after each tab the state has some more data and the next (or only final) tab receives it.

Comment: I think I see what you are telling me... So in my case the handleSubmit will be trigerred by the onClick on the tabs to send the data to a right place. Then my submit button will make the HTTP call on his own.

Comment: Yes, I coudln't make out how you handle the other forms, but if they don't have a "submit" button you need to do that on click of tabs. Collect all form data and push it to the state of the upper component (Note: you have to merge all tabs data, so make sure oyu don't overwirte it while changing tabs)

Comment: But when use redux, I should have a global object where I can refer to anywhere ? In my second tab why I can't do something like `getStore('nameOfTheFormInReduxForm')` and merge data from here ?

Comment: Yes, obviously the redux store is a good place for the data if you have one :D
So if your forms product appropriate actions and get their data stored in the redux store you can get them from there in the final step. That would be optimal.

Comment: That what I'm trying to get working ! I can console log the current form but not the entire state :(

Comment: Did you actually create and connect a redux store to your components? Did you try to use redux developer addon for your browser to check the store content?

Comment: Yes that what i'm digging right now... But when I click on my tab the previous form object is deleted. redux-form/DESTROY is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166977/discussion-between-christianm-and-ragnar).

Comment: you should make different forms in each component.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `destroyOnUnmount` flag to `false` in reduxForm(options).